# The proof of $c_1(E)\in \tilde{H}^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ when $E\to X$ is a complex line bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $E\to X$ be a complex line bundle. Let $\tilde{H}^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ denote the image of $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ in $H^2(X, \mathbb{R})$ under the natural homomorphism induced by the inclusion of the constant sheaves $Z\subset R $

I am reading the proof of $c_1(E)\in \tilde{H^2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ from Well's book, and on Well's book, it says that:
[image]

I wonder why it suffices to show that $c_1(U_{1,N})\in H^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$?

By $c_1(U_{1,N})\in H^2(U_{1,N},\mathbb{R})$ and $\Phi:X\to G_{1,N}=P_{N-1}$, we see $\Phi^*(c_1(U_{1,N})\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ if $c_1(U_{1,N})\in H^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$, but then why do we have $\Phi^*(c_1(U_{1,N}))\in \tilde{H^2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$? I don't think it's true that ${H^2}(X,\mathbb{Z})\subset \tilde{H^2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

The definition of $\Phi$ for the case of bundle with rank $r$ is given below:
[image]

Comment: what is Well's book you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not even meaningful to say that $c_1(U_{1,N})\in H^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$.  By definition, $c_1(U_{1,N})$ is an element of $H^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{R})$, and $H^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$ is not a subset of $H^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{R})$; only $\tilde{H}^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$ is.  So, I would assume this is either a typo or a mild abuse of notation: the natural map from $H^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$ to $\tilde{H}^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism, so they can be treated as interchangeable.

Comment: Is that generally true that if $\phi: M\to N$, then $\phi^*:\tilde{H}^n(N)\to \tilde{H}^n(M)$?

Comment: Yes: if $x\in \tilde{H}^n(N,\mathbb{Z})$ is the image of $y\in H^n(N,\mathbb{Z})$, then $\phi^*(x)$ is the image of $\phi^*(y)$ and hence in $\tilde{H}^n(M,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: But why does the pullback stay in the image?

Comment: The isomorphism $H^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})\cong\tilde{H}^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$, is that because $H^2(P_{N-1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}=\tilde{H}^2(P_{N-1},\mathbb{Z})$?